# How to get one row per each item from and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have following mysql table:

```
---+-------+------------+----------
id | price |   e_date   | item_name
---+-------+------------+----------
 1 | 1000  | 2015-01-01 | pen
 2 | 1050  | 2015-02-01 | pen
 3 | 850   | 2015-03-01 | pen
 4 | 800   | 2015-03-20 | pen
 5 | 1150  | 2015-04-01 | pen
 6 | 750   | 2015-02-01 | pencil
 7 | 900   | 2015-03-01 | pencil
 8 | 950   | 2015-03-15 | pencil
---+-------+------------+----------
```

If I query the table:

```
"SELECT item_name,price as p,e_date FROM test_table WHERE (item_name='pen' or item_name='pencil') AND e_date<='$e_date'"
//(*Here $e_date gets from user input)
```

The fetched result is as follows:

```
Price of pen is 1000 on 2015-01-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
Price of pen is 1050 on 2015-02-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
Price of pen is 850 on 2015-03-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
Price of pencil is 750 on 2015-02-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
Price of pencil is 900 on 2015-03-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
```

But I want the result will contain only one row per item_name like:

```
Price of pen is 850 on 2015-03-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
Price of pencil is 900 on 2015-03-01 against user input: 2015-03-01
```

Result should be the price from the most recent date which is less than the user input date for each item.
How to achieve that?

Comment: That _is_ the result you get. Do you mean it should only be the most recent price, before the date you are searching?

Comment: `ORDER BY e_date DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Yes pala_, it must be most recent price before the date an user is searching

Comment: And is there a possibility that there will be more than one price change on a date?

Comment: RST Limit will not work in this case because it will not return price for both pen and pencil items. It will return only price of pen item.

Comment: `ORDER BY e_date DESC LIMIT 1` will fetch the single row with latest `e_date`.

Comment: No, there will be only one price for a particular date per item.

Comment: okay, that makes it a little easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to determine the most recent date, earlier than your search query. per item.

```
select item_name, max(e_date) e_date
  from test_table
  where e_date < '$e_date'
  group by item_name
```

We then join against this query to retrieve the rest of the results:

```
select t.* 
  from test_table t
    inner join (
    select item_name, max(e_date) e_date
      from test_table
      where e_date < '$e_date'
      group by item_name
    ) q
    on t.item_name = q.item_name
      and t.e_date = q.e_date
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da7f0/2) that shows desired behaviour

Comment: Thankyou very much pala_, this is the output that I want. Thanks for your efforts from yesterday in order to solve my problem.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid Using 2015-03-01 in the fiddle doesn't return the result you specified. Shouldn't the code look for `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: Yes, I already corrected that code. Also, I can limit the search among the items (suppose there are 25000 item_name) if I use WHERE item_name=pen OR item_name=pencil  and ....... so on before e_date <= '$e_date' for limited number of items. This will reduce the query time. But pala_ has shown me the guide.